# Create .exe file in php with mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, exe

i have developed in-house software for hotel management system using PHP/MYSQL. Our Client wants Software in .exe format and used in desktop. i use various softwares for .exe conversion  but it only support php but i want's to connect with MySQL Database. Please anyone can help to create .exe conversion with MySQL Database..

Answer (score 5):

1. Download [PHP Desktop Chrome](https://github.com/cztomczak/phpdesktop/wiki/Download-Chrome#stable-releases).
2. Copy all your code from site directory to `Phpdesktopchrome/www` directory.
3. Run Phpdesktopchrome.exe, it will execute like a browser with PHP compiler.
4. Download [Innosetup Software](http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php) for make exe file.
5. Install and run Innosetup and select Phpdesktop chrome files to create a EXE file in Option.
6. Install wampserver in client system with database import.
7. Enjoy.

Answer (score 3):

There are many compliers available on web by which you can create EXE in PHP.
This program runs through dos and windows only... :) so this is good news for windows user

1. First Download zip from [Here](http://www.bambalam.se/bamcompile/).
2. Now unzip it and open Command prompt and then go to its directory location.
3. Start -> run then type ‘cmd’
4. Use the “cd..” command to change directory.
5. Place PHP script to be compiled next to bamcompile.exe place it in same directory.
6. In the cmd prompt, at that directory, type:

   ```
   bamcompile test.php
   ```

variations:

```
bamcompile -c test.php gives compression.
-e:something.dll allows a DLL to be embedded
```

Ready made examples are given in Zipped files which you have downloaded,just try it out.
Another application wapache is also there but i dont know much about it.

Comment: The answer is missing the download link.  Please edit the answer to provide this information.

Answer (score 3):

DOWNLOAD WAMP server from wampserver.com.
its very good for offline use server for desktop, then just copy and paste you script abd .sql file into it. and you are Done.

If your client using highspeed interenet then they can connect the server to online. but they need super computer for more traffic, another option is LAN.

If the program is for office use and no need to connect a lot of computer and internet then use LAN and WAMP.

------  Another possible you can use  --------

1. Install WAMP then copy then .exe file "click start button > all program > and paste into startup folder". server will run automatic windows OS start or restart but it take 2-3 min. (green light)
2. go to wamp folder > www > make a folder for your program then paste your script.
3. open any browser then in address bar type "localhost or 127.0.0.1 (localhost IP for offline)" , scroll down and you will see "Your Projects" and under of this you will see your folder which you had create into wamp server > www folder. click on  it and here you gooooo....
4. Now your client can do work with your script. Bookmark it and also create a shortcut into desktop for direct use.

Hope this may help you. thank you.

If you are getting any problem to do this work, then email me here - (krishnabiker@yahoo.com)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should just convince your client not to use a .exe installer. It makes no sense.

You could have an installer that installs a local webserver and a local MySQL, and then opens a web browser and browses the local webserver. This would work, but it means your application runs on only one machine, and can't be used by two people.

On the other hand, you could install an application that talks to a central MySQL database, hosted on the LAN. But then why not install the entire application (webserver, MySQL etc) on the LAN, and have the clients access it across the LAN as a web application? Still no reason for a local install.

I would suggest:

1. See if you can persuade your client to move to an entirely web-hosted solution. Emphasize how easy updates are - from one central location, not from each machine; or
2. See if you client won't be happy with a .exe that installs a link to a URL (on the LAN).

Answer (score 0):

VERY SHORT ANSWER: NOT POSSIBLE

Tell your client that it is a client-server application not a desktop app.

One idea is to have portable PHP/MYSQL/APACHE that can be stored in a CD or used and create an autorun fro it..

Answer (score 0):

Tell your client you can do better than that, you can create a batch file for his use!

Then create a program.bat file with one line that runs the php (should be something like "php ").

:)

Answer (score 0):

We need to bundle your project files in MSI ( windows installer ) along with PHP frameworks, MySQL and Apache.

Everything can be included in a single MSI file or you can keep server part in one MSI (PHP framework+Apache framework+ MySQL) and your Project file along with Yiiframework in another MSI.

I already made server part MSI in order to create one of my previous web project. In that project i had to configure Mysql DB (my.ini) and Apache configuration file (.conf). It worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

For a desktop application I recommend that you change your database settings (if you can) and switch to SQLite3 DB. They are portable files and does not need a database server to run.

Answer (score -2):

Use http://www.usbwebserver.com/ and from a stick or an CD/DVD you will be able to run your application. It is a portable version similar to W